# Adding Font-Awsome Icon with Semantic UI

Tags: javascript, reactjs, font-awesome, semantic-ui

I have a semantic UI menu with icons, but on the dropdown-expand menu option i cant seem to add any icons.
i wish to add `<i className="fa fa-gavel fa-lg"/>` to the first line.

```
     <Dropdown /*Here i want a font-awsome icon */ item text="Language" pointing='left'>
         <Dropdown.Menu>
                 <Dropdown.Header><FormattedMessage id="navigationBar.chooseLanguage"/></Dropdown.Header>
                 <Dropdown.Item onClick={() => this.props.setLocale("en")}> <img src={ENG} alt="Eng" /> <p className="lang"> English     </p> </Dropdown.Item> <hr/>
                 <Dropdown.Item onClick={() => this.props.setLocale("se")}> <img src={SWE} alt="Swe" /> <p className="lang"> Svenska     </p> </Dropdown.Item> <hr/>
                 <Dropdown.Item onClick={() => this.props.setLocale("de")}> <img src={DEN} alt="Den" /> <p className="lang"> Dansk       </p> </Dropdown.Item> <hr/>
                 <Dropdown.Item onClick={() => this.props.setLocale("no")}> <img src={NOR} alt="Nor" /> <p className="lang"> Norsk       </p> </Dropdown.Item>
         </Dropdown.Menu>
     </Dropdown>
```

All suggestions on how to solve this issue are much appreciated.

Comment: are you using typescript?

Comment: Not in this project :)

Comment: So, what is happening that you can't add icon? what error or problem happens?

Comment: Syntax/Compile error

Comment: Semantic-UI-react has a complete set of FontAwesome icons, and Dropdown has `icon` attribute/prop `<Dropdown icon="...." />` does not work?

Comment: and what is that `Syntax/Compile error` ? what code have you added that gets those error? why haven't you put that code in the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SUIR has support for both FA icons and flags, try using the following code

```
<Dropdown
  options={[
    { text: 'English', value: 'en', flag: 'gb' },
    { text: 'Svenska', value: 'se', flag: 'se' },
    { text: 'Dansk', value: 'de', flag: 'de' },
    { text: 'Norsk', value: 'no', flag: 'no' },
  ]}
  text="Language"
  icon="gavel"
  pointing="left"
/>
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/405kw8w3n9?fontsize=14&module=%2Fexample.js